# Window.location.reload(true) in CRM 2013

Tags: javascript, refresh, crm

When using the function window.location.reload(true), it refreshes an old form, but when a New form is opened,some information is saved but the form is not closed, when I refresh it opend a new blank form. How can i move around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**use:**

Xrm.Page.data.refresh(save).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

Save:
A Boolean value to indicate if data should be saved after it is refreshed.

**to refresh sub-grid use:**

Xrm.Page.getControl('your sub-grid name').refresh();

**to refresh webRessource use this:**

var url=Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get(webRessourceName);
url.setSrc(url.getSrc());

Comment: why not rather `location.reload()`?